# update the function and get iteration results from scipy

Tags: python, scipy

```
def f(params):
    pi12, pi21 = params
    LL = 10*np.log(40*60/110**2) + 30*np.log(40*50/110**2) + 20*np.log(20/110*(50/110 + 60/110*pi12)) + \ 
         50*np.log(50/110*(60/110 + 50/110*pi21)) - 110*np.log(40*60/110**2 + 40*50/110**2 + \
         20/110*(50/110 + 60/110*pi12) + 50/110*(60/110 + 50/110*pi21))
    return -LL

def callbackF(Xi):
    global Nfeval
    print('pass callback',str(Nfeval))
    print(Nfeval, Xi[0], Xi[1], f(Xi))
    Nfeval += 1

initial_guess = [0, 0]
b = (0.0, 1.0)
b0 = b1 = b
bnb = [b0, b1]
res = minimize(f, initial_guess, bounds=bnb, method='bfgs', callback=callbackF, options={'disp':True})
print (res)
```

I am trying to capture the optimal result for the objective function, but it always shows [1, 1]. Ideally I should get two parameters constrained between 0 and 1 to maximize the -LL. Did I do anything wrong? I wonder if I should update the objective function after each iteration, but I am quite confused how to make it work. I have checked several posts but still not sure. Other reading materials are also very welcom. Thanks a lot!

Here is the results part!

```
pass callback 25
25 0.6870283538140954 0.7403323855238932 143.98656641020855
pass callback 26
26 0.7935216169001177 0.7090801503785442 143.93658208323882
pass callback 27
27 0.8314173041320377 0.7666686643426496 143.84748818067345
pass callback 28
28 0.9264732632840973 0.8980814706430704 143.7237871814941
pass callback 29
29 0.9885339111975429 0.9836968132795704 143.69759782341296
pass callback 30
30 0.999243206123829 0.9988036732413753 143.69694856450647
pass callback 31
31 1.0000109917713558 0.9999811482899945 143.6969451785149
pass callback 32
32 1.0000049364520325 0.99999836986115 143.6969451768374
pass callback 33
33 1.000000303283094 1.000000360615374 143.6969451767528
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 143.696945
         Iterations: 9
         Function evaluations: 44
         Gradient evaluations: 11
      fun: 143.6969451767528
 hess_inv: array([[0.2255719 , 0.08676943],
       [0.08676943, 0.21320636]])
      jac: array([1.90734863e-06, 3.81469727e-06])
  message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nfev: 44
      nit: 9
     njev: 11
   status: 0
  success: True
        x: array([1.0000003 , 1.00000036])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the optimizer is finding the correct minimum at [1,1]. Here is a plot of your function:

[image]

And here is the code I used to generate that plot.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

def f(params):
    pi12, pi21 = params
    LL = 10*np.log(40*60/110**2) + 30*np.log(40*50/110**2) + 20*np.log(20/110*(50/110 + 60/110*pi12)) + \
         50*np.log(50/110*(60/110 + 50/110*pi21)) - 110*np.log(40*60/110**2 + 40*50/110**2 + \
         20/110*(50/110 + 60/110*pi12) + 50/110*(60/110 + 50/110*pi21))
    return -LL

def g(X,Y):
    return f([X,Y])

initial_guess = [0, 0]
b = (0.0, 1.0)
b0 = b1 = b
bnb = [b0, b1]
res = minimize(f, initial_guess, bounds=bnb, method='bfgs')

print (res)


X = np.arange(0, 1, 0.05)
Y = np.arange(0, 1, 0.05)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
Z = g(X,Y)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

# Plot the surface.
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

plt.show()
```